# Python library that check if a semi-complete-word exist in the English dictionary

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to find if python has a library that support finding a semi-completed word that exist in the English language.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do, giving **'-eriod'** the English language would be **'period'** or **'enou--h'** the English language would be **'enough'**

I have looked up about PyDictionary but it only provides function such as definition, synonym, tranlations, so I was wonder do python has a library that supports finding words in the English dictionary ?

Comment: I don't know about dictionary stuff, but the regex library, `re` sounds like it would be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download a dictionary file with one word per line in your current directory, this getmatches() function using the re library should work:

```
import re

with open('dictionary.txt') as file:
    words = [w[:-1] for w in file.readlines()]
    
def getmatches(matchstring):
    matchstring = matchstring.replace('-', '.')
    return [word for word in words if re.fullmatch(matchstring, word)]

print(getmatches('-eriod'))
print(getmatches('enou-h'))
```